# Oracle merge INTO , not doing an insert

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a record when there is no match Or do an Update when there is a match

This is my SQL Query

```
merge INTO employee_identity tgt USING (
  select 
    e.employee_id, 
    eid.emp_cus_value, 
    eid.emp_doj 
  from 
    employee e 
    join employee_channel ec on e.employee_id = ec.employee_id 
    left join employee_identity eid on e.employee_id = eid.employee_id 
  where 
    ec.employee_channel_id = 53
) src ON (
  tgt.employee_id = src.employee_id
) WHEN NOT matched THEN INSERT (
  tgt.employee_identity_id, tgt.employee_id, 
  tgt.emp_cus_value, tgt.emp_doj
) 
VALUES 
  (3, 1121, 404, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 WHEN matched THEN UPDATE 
SET 
  tgt.emp_cus_value = tgt.emp_cus_value + 10;
```

The issue I am facing is that , no insert is happening when the select doesn't return any match .
Update is fine .

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9d6fb/5

Answer (score 2):

According to data you posted, this is target table contents:

```
SQL> select * from employee_identity;

EMPLOYEE_IDENTITY_ID EMPLOYEE_ID EMP_CUS_VALUE EMP_DOJ
-------------------- ----------- ------------- ----------
                   1        1121           404 07.04.2023
                   2        1122           604 07.04.2023  --> this is the match
```

The 2nd row *matches* data returned by the `USING` subquery:

```
SQL>   select
  2      e.employee_id,
  3      eid.emp_cus_value,
  4      eid.emp_doj
  5    from
  6      employee e
  7      join employee_channel ec on e.employee_id = ec.employee_id
  8      left join employee_identity eid on e.employee_id = eid.employee_id
  9    where
 10      ec.employee_channel_id = 51;

EMPLOYEE_ID EMP_CUS_VALUE EMP_DOJ
----------- ------------- ----------
       1122           604 07.04.2023

SQL>
```

Therefore, there's nothing to `INSERT`.

---

However, if you delete matching row from the target table:

```
SQL> delete from employee_identity where employee_identity_id = 2;

1 row deleted.

SQL> select * from employee_identity;

EMPLOYEE_IDENTITY_ID EMPLOYEE_ID EMP_CUS_VALUE EMP_DOJ
-------------------- ----------- ------------- ----------
                   1        1121           404 07.04.2023

SQL>
```

and run `merge`:

```
SQL> merge INTO employee_identity tgt USING (
  2    select
  3      e.employee_id,
  4      eid.emp_cus_value,
  5      eid.emp_doj
  6    from
  7      employee e
  8      join employee_channel ec on e.employee_id = ec.employee_id
  9      left join employee_identity eid on e.employee_id = eid.employee_id
 10    where
 11      ec.employee_channel_id = 51
 12  ) src ON (
 13    tgt.employee_id = src.employee_id
 14  ) WHEN NOT matched THEN INSERT (
 15    tgt.employee_identity_id, tgt.employee_id,
 16    tgt.emp_cus_value, tgt.emp_doj
 17  )
 18  VALUES
 19    (3, 1121, 404, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 20   WHEN matched THEN UPDATE
 21  SET
 22    tgt.emp_cus_value = tgt.emp_cus_value + 10;

1 row merged.

SQL>
```

and check the result, here's your *missing* row which was **inserted** during `merge`:

```
SQL> select * from employee_identity;

EMPLOYEE_IDENTITY_ID EMPLOYEE_ID EMP_CUS_VALUE EMP_DOJ
-------------------- ----------- ------------- ----------
                   1        1121           404 07.04.2023
                   3        1121           404 07.04.2023   --> here it is

SQL>
```

Therefore, I'd say that it *is* working as expected. Or did I miss the point?